# How are antibodies extracted from donor blood?

Tags: hematology, antibody, blood-transfusion

When blood is donated, the antibodies within it are extracted, but how exactly do they do it? How do they take out the antibodies within the blood, what process do they go through?

Comment: Do you have a source that the antibodies are removed?

Comment: Just look at it, if they didn't remove the donor's antibodies only people with the same blood types could donate. If the antibodies weren't taken out for example type O wouldn't be a universal donor. O has A and B antibodies so it wouldn't be compatible with any other types. In order for it to be the universal donor(which it is) the antibodies of the donor blood must be removed. It's also common knowledge, but here is the logical explanation for Chris.

Comment: This is the reason why O- (universal donor) is so much sought after. And why blood for some blood groups is easier available (A + for example) than for others. Oh, and belittling other users is always a bad idea since you want something. There is no obligation to write an answer, though.

Comment: I am really sorry Chris if you thought I was belittling you. I didn't see my answer having an offensive tone, sorry if it did. I was just trying to answer your question so if others stumble upon this and have the same question the answer would be present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe they do remove the antibodies but rather they match and screen the [donor antigen and antibody profiles to those of the recipient.](http://www.bloodbook.com/compat.html) The process is very briefly outlined on the [Red Cross website](http://www.redcrossblood.org/learn-about-blood/what-happens-donated-blood);

> 1. Most blood is spun in centrifuges to separate the transfusable components – red cells, platelets, and plasma
> 2. The primary components like plasma, can be further manufactured into components such as cryoprecipitate
> 3. Red cells are then leuko-reduced
> 4. Single donor platelets are leukoreduced and bacterially tested.

[The article in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_type#Blood_transfusion) explains the screening for blood transfusions;

> Patients should ideally receive their own blood or type-specific blood products to minimize the chance of a transfusion reaction. Risks can be further reduced by cross-matching blood, but this may be skipped when blood is required for an emergency. Cross-matching involves mixing a sample of the recipient's serum with a sample of the donor's red blood cells and checking if the mixture agglutinates, or forms clumps. If agglutination is not obvious by direct vision, blood bank technicians usually check for agglutination with a microscope. If agglutination occurs, that particular donor's blood cannot be transfused to that particular recipient.

Comment: Thanks Michael_A, if you have time to answer a follow up question here it is. Are all the antibodies and antigens in the centrifuged blood removed or do some necessary antibodies get transferred to the patient.

Comment: @genius Antibodies are not removed by centrifugation - they stay in solution. When you spin so high, that antibodies precipitate, all the cellular components of the blood will not survive this.

Comment: I believe the antibodies are predominantly in the plasma component. Cross-matching donor and recipient blood tests for the presence of problematic antigen-antibody interactions.